# How to use 7z.dll?

Tags: dll, inno-setup

I have now a script to download a file and copy to a directory. But how could i make it so that if i compress a folder to a zip file , and then would need to extract it when that zipped folder is downloaded. It's takes too much time to to write the lines for every file separately. I know that i could use 7z.dll to decompress, but dont know how to put that in code.

```
 [Code]
    procedure InitializeWizard;
    begin
      idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
    end;

    procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
    begin
      if CurPageID = wpReady then
      begin
        idpClearFiles;

        if IsComponentSelected('IGR') then

          idpAddFile('http://www.mediafire.com/download/f9hnlkt1t75ykjk/waterfall_IGR.model', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\waterfall_IGR.model'));
      end;
    end;

    procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
    begin
      if CurStep = ssPostInstall then 
      begin
        // Copy downloaded files to application directory
        FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\waterfall_IGR.model'), ExpandConstant('{app}\res_mods\0.8.10\content\Environment\env_waterfall\waterfall_IGR.model'), false);
      end;
    end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if `7z.dll` will work directly, but what can be done is to download 7zip portable, include its folder in your package and pass the unzipping command to `7za.exe` .

Eg :
`7za.exe x <path to>\in.zip -oc:\pathToOutFolder`

Comment: ...I would make a few extension tool libraries like e.g. service controller (I promised to write it in script, but library would be much better), this archiver, new downloader (which I have started to work on), some sort of image control (with PNG and some fading support), etc. But, there are at least three problems with all of that. I'm not the one who would be satisfied to release something untested or unstable, currently I don't know anyone who would contribute to those projects (people around me are usually lazy :-) And, I'm working on a full time project (quite a big GIS).

Comment: @TLama , Its fine buddy, its ok to have a little debate sometimes. You are right about the black Box though.

Comment: @jyrka , I just asked someone trustworthy who uses `7z.exe` to generate a zip pack in c#.net. They say there isn't any black Box. You will really have to try to find out what happens in your case.

Comment: Sure you can. It might look [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/ejgJTSqp). However, that will execute after the installation process. Please note, I haven't tested this script (no time). @codin, feel free to put it into your answer (if it works) if you want to ;-)

Comment: @TLama i know the {app} is chosen directory :-) , just that if the setup downloads the file, it should extract it to {app} as is in the script, but nothing appears in the install folder

Comment: @jyrka, sorry. I really need to take a break... Instead of `-oc:\{app}\Extracted` I have used there it should be just `-o{app}\Extracted`. I thought, I don't know why, that the `-oc:\ ` is the command line switch, but it was just `-o`, that `c:\ ` part was a drive root. Well, might have been better to show it e.g. as `<path to output folder>` in the same manner as `<path to>` though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when create a 7zip file and split it out in several smnall files using the -v option, the way I fixed is using powershell I get the list of files and the create dynamically the Inno project, it looks something like

```
$Files = Get-Item "$zipFilesLocation\*.*" 
$files | Select-object @{Name="Address"; Expression={"idpAddFile('<webaddress>" + $_.Name + "' ,  ExpandConstant('{tmp}\58-Formulary_201311.7z.001'));"}}
 and tghen just write each object into the iss file like 

foreach ($elem in $files)
{
$e = "idpAddFile( WebWrlString + '" + $elem.Name + "', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\"  + $elem.Name + "'));"
    $e | Out-File "Innopackage.iss" -Encoding ASCII  -Append
}
```

I hope this helps